# Push properties/variables into an object in WebStorm (javascript refactoring)

Tags: javascript, variables, properties, refactoring, webstorm

Does WebStorm support pushing variable declarations into objects?  For the following simplified example, refactor such that `bar` is a property of `myObject`.  References to bar should be updated to resemble references to `foo`.

```
var myObject = {
    foo : new foo()
};
var bar = new bar();

myObject.foo.blah = "something";
bar.blah = "something else";
```

Find-Replace is not sufficient; I would like to capitalize on WebStorm's intelligent refactoring.  Note that Refactor->Rename does not allow identifiers containing a period.  In WebStorm 9 an inline Refactor->Rename allowed renaming a variable to include a period (but obviously wouldn't create the required property declaration).